# BPMN 2.0 confused about execute process

Tags: jboss, bpel, business-process-management, bpmn

Im a little confused about BPMN 2.0 Engines

if you have modeled a process on the BPMN 2.0 standard in a BPM engine like activiti, activeVOS or JBOSS and you want to execute that process, the engine converts that BPMN "code" into another kind of code (like BPEL, XPDL, etc) or there is a way to "execute BPMN 2.0"?

There are some engines like IBM BPM that offers you only BPMN in their "basic" product, so, that product "executes" BPMN directly? or converts its in some way?

the same ocurred with JBOSS, if u model a BMPN process u can execute it?

Kind regards

Answer (score 3):

BPMN 2.0 is an OMG specification that you can find [here](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/)
The specification describes several level of comprehension. In your case, what you are interested in are ;"Process Modeling Conformance" and "Process Execution Performance".
The specification also provide rules for serialization which is based on XML.

Some editors are using this serialization internally, some others not. In the second case, most of the time they provide import/export in bpmn 2 format.

What you have to be aware is that, even if a lot of  execution behaviors has been defined, there is still a lot of points where it is missing or at least not all vendors interprets the specification exactly the same.

The [BPMN Model Interchange Working Group](http://www.omgwiki.org/bpmn-miwg/doku.php?id=start) is working to file the gap and provide guidelines for a proper serialization and exchange of BPMN files between vendors.

To sum up, the short answer is: it doesn't really matters if they execute it directly of if they convert it internally. The only important thing is that the behavior respects the "Process Execution Conformance".

Regards,